# Most efficient way to store only the date?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, datetime, smalldatetime

> DateTime is accurate to three-hundredths of a second. SmallDateTime is
>   accurate to one minute.

What if you only need accuracy to a day? What is the best practice here? I realise that a DateTime is 8 bytes, and SmallDateTime is only 4; but I am just wondering is there a better or more suitable way to store only a date value than creating a column of SmallDateTime and saving SmallDateTime.Date in it ?

Every little helps! :)

Comment: And your version of SQL Server is...?

Comment: You have seen the Date (only) type in SQL 2008? 3 Bytes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: What environment are you developing in which is going to be noticeably affected by a few bytes?

Comment: Ask yourself if you really need to do this optimization? [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain't_gonna_need_it)

Comment: @KirkWoll 2008
ThePower I never said it would be drastically affected. I like to use best practice irrespective of this.
YAGNI-Ian See above! :)

Comment: as @nonnb said, you should use the `DATE` datatype then

Comment: @Ian you don't know the scenario, so YAGNI doesn't apply. perhaps this is an indexed column with 200 million rows so you would like to make sure your index stays in memory

Comment: @nonnb thanks very much, I was not aware of this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what version of SQL Server you are running.

- 2008+: Date
- 2008-: SmallDateTime

Although, if you look at the [documentation for smalldatetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277.aspx), they use a two-byte integer for date and two-byte integer for time, so you could likely replicate their behavior and just store a two-byte integer (smallint) and then use DateAdd to add the number of days since 1900/1/1 if size is *really* that important in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Use the 3 byte Date. See [`Date` data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx)